# AngularJS - UI Router - flickering after check login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have this problem with angular: i have in my router system a control to the user's authentication. The code below:

```
// ROUTING
function config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/home');

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404")

    $stateProvider
        // link HOME
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/home/_home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            data: {
                privatePage: false,                 
                publicPage: false
            }
        })
        // link CONTATTI
        .state('contatti', {
            url: '/contatti',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/contatti/_contatti.html',
            controller: 'ContattiController',
            data: {
                privatePage: true,                  
                publicPage: false
            } 
        })
        // link REGISTRAZIONE
        .state('registration', {
            url: '/registration',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/registration/_registration.html',
            controller: 'RegistrationController',
            data: {
                privatePage: false,                 
                publicPage: true
            } 
        })

        // error pages
        .state('404', {
            url: '/404',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/404/_404.html',
            data: {
                privatePage: false,                 
                publicPage: false
            } 
        })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}

// CHECK 
function run ($rootScope, $state, SessionService) {

    $rootScope.$state = $state; 

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to) {
        var isLogged;
        return SessionService.getSession() // Creo la sessione utente
            .then(function(response){
                isLogged = ($rootScope.$session.id_login ? true : false);

                var isPrivatePage = to.data.privatePage;
                var isPublicPage = to.data.publicPage;

                if((isPrivatePage && !isLogged)||(isPublicPage && isLogged)){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $state.go('home');
                }

            }); 
    });
}
```

All works fine, but when I'm not logged and click to CONTATTI, the browser show me for a moment that page and before it redirects to HOME. It should not be displaying CONTATTI at all if they are not logged in. Is there a system to avoid this effect?
Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that you can briefly see the private page when you're not logged in, and you don't want them to view it even for that brief moment, correct?

Comment: exactly! i don't want them to view it!

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/home'); and $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404") should be at the bottom.

Comment: I would also suggest to use 403 instead of 404, as you don't have permissions. I would not describe it as page not existing.

Comment: @digit: thanks, i did it. I change it but nothing change in website

Comment: If your application can't be accessed without being logged, an efficient solution is to use the `resolve` parameters of the root state to load the current session and redirect if there is none.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can reside inside the:

```
return SessionService.getSession() // Creo la sessione utente
        .then(function(response){
            ...

            if((isPrivatePage && !isLogged)||(isPublicPage && isLogged)){
                e.preventDefault();
                $state.go('home');
            }
        });
```

From what I understand, `SessionService.getSession()` is an async call (I suppose that because it returns a promise) and so it introduce a bit of delay. During this delay the "CONTATTI" page is displayed then the promise of `SessionService.getSession()` is resolved and inside the handler function you call `$state.go('home');` and only a that point the "home" page is loaded.

To fix it you should, as first thing, prevent the default behavior so the "CONTATTI" page is not loaded by default then you should manage manually the transition to "CONTATTI" page, something like that:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
    var isLogged;
    e.preventDefault(); // 1. Always prevent the default behaviour
    return SessionService.getSession() // Creo la sessione utente
        .then(function(response){
            isLogged = ($rootScope.$session.id_login ? true : false);

            var isPrivatePage = to.data.privatePage;
            var isPublicPage = to.data.publicPage;

            if((isPrivatePage && !isLogged)||(isPublicPage && isLogged)){
                $state.go('home');
            } else { 
                // 2. Manage the default case
                $state.go(to, toParams, options);
            }
        }, function(error) {
            // Manage error returned by getSession.
            // You can redirect to home state
            $state.go('home');
            // or to another error state..
            //$state.go('error');
        }); 
});
```

Comment: I guess the same so.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks very much for your complete answer.
I change my code like your suggest, but now nothing appear on the "ui-view" when i open the base url (http://local.website.it/home). 
Why do this?

Comment: Maybe `SessionService.getSession()` return a rejected promise which is not managed by the `then` method. Rejected promises are managed by a second handler passed to `then` method. I updated the snippet above.

Comment: Now return an error on console: Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D) and like before, nothing appear on "ui-view".

Comment: Can you provide a working piece of code in a plunker/jsfiddle, please? It's really hard to help someone without having a real piece of working code we can analyze, run and check... Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Andrea for your suggest. I hope this is ok: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JNXbTlEtKhOipUzdkKin?p=info)

Comment: I tried it but I am not able to reproduce you last error with that Plunker, how can I? Can you explain to us how to reproduce it?

Comment: I update the code, but it doesn't work! Can you help me? I put all code in Plunker!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot... You cannot simply put the code on plunker, you have to be sure to be able to reproduce the error you are asking help for... Again, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 

And, by the way, I answered your question, so I would really be glad if you can accept it.

Comment: Hi Andrea! Ok, i reproduce the error on Plunker. I had to add comment line on $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart') because it gone on loop cycle. Can you help me now with it?

Comment: Hi Andrea, are you still trying to look at my problem?

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, a view is seem by a user in a short time whom needs to be redirected to STS (or login state, or some other mechanism) for authentication result. And during this short period of time, you don't want anything to be seem by user.

I can advice a practical solution I used;
you can put a `hidden` class (assuming you have boostrap) to `body` of your `index.html` like:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController" class="hiden">
```

then on your `app.run` function you can check it like:

```
angular.module("myModule")
    .run(appRun);
appRun.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$state", "SessionService"];

function appRun($rootScope,  $state, SessionService) {

  var isLogged = ($rootScope.$session.id_login ? true : false);

    if (isLogged) {            
        angular.element('body').removeClass('hidden');  
    } else {
        return SessionService.getSession() // Creo la sessione utente
        .then(function(response){
            isLogged = ($rootScope.$session.id_login ? true : false);

            var isPrivatePage = to.data.privatePage;
            var isPublicPage = to.data.publicPage;

            if((isPrivatePage && !isLogged)||(isPublicPage && isLogged)){
                e.preventDefault();
                $state.go('home');
            }

        }); 
    }
}
```